# redux-form, change fields value without changing dirty state

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a field that shouldn't have effect on form's dirty state. 
Is there a way to change it's value without changing it's dirty state?
Can I set it's initial value somehow, without initializing whole form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution; but I warn you, it's not very pretty.

In your `reducer.plugin()`, you get passed `state` and `action`. The form is considered dirty if the `state.values` object is equal to the `state.initial` object (they are compared in [isPristine.js](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/496b21ddb5e852038d8365a83b23f62d3e68d6a6/src/selectors/isPristine.js)). The reducer returns the new state, so in the reducer I changed `initial`.

See what I do to `specialField` here:

```
return {
  ...state,
  /* snip */

  initial: {
    ...state.initial,
    specialField
  }
}
```

Maybe that's subverting something important, but it worked for me.

Hope this helps!